# "Enter Parameter Value" dialog box appears when I run my query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form that contains two text boxes to search for a first name and a last name and a button to run the query. However, when the button is clicked, the enter parameter value dialog box appears for each text feild. Also, I have another textbox and button to search for positions, same thing happens. I created a test database and form at home in access 2007 using the same code (using 2010 at work), and the dialog box doesn't appear. I'm pretty new to access, so it's possible I'm overlooking something. But, I'm clueless to as what it is. I've search here and google for a solution, but nothing has worked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT dbo_Apptable.AppID, dbo_Apptable.Date, dbo_Apptable.Position, dbo_Apptable.Referral, dbo_Apptable.LastName, dbo_Apptable.FirstName
FROM dbo_Apptable
WHERE (((dbo_Apptable.LastName) Like "*" & Forms![Main Menu]![Last Name] & "*") And ((dbo_Apptable.FirstName) Like "*" & Forms![Main Menu]![First Name] & "*"));


SELECT dbo_Apptable.AppID, dbo_Apptable.Date, dbo_Apptable.Position, dbo_Apptable.Referral, dbo_Apptable.LastName, dbo_Apptable.FirstName
FROM dbo_Apptable
WHERE (((dbo_Apptable.Position) Like "*" & [Forms]![Main Menu]![Position] & "*"));
```

Comment: I tested a similar example, and the syntax looks ok. Are you sure the controls are named like that? [Last Name] and [First Name] with spaces in them?

And are you sure the form is still open (in normal view) when the query is run? If the form is closed you will get the dialogs.

Comment: Yeah, that's the correct name of the controls and the form is open when I run the query. @Wietze314

Answer (score 2):

You indicated `[Main Menu]` is open in Form View when you run those queries and the control names are correct.  Yet Access asks you to supply values for the form controls.  That means the db engine can't find those form controls, and I don't understand why that is happening.

I suggest you try a simpler query which focuses on only those controls.

```sql
SELECT
    Forms![Main Menu]![Last Name] AS main_menu_last_name,
    Forms![Main Menu]![First Name] AS main_menu_first_name,
    Forms![Main Menu]![Position] AS main_menu_position
```

That query won't cure the problem but it may help avoid distraction from other parts of the queries.

If this simple query also fails, triple-check the names of the form controls.  Since you're new to Access, perhaps you have a text box whose caption is *"Last Name"*, but the name of the text box control is actually something like *"Text1"*.

On the other hand, if Access gives you the values of those form controls without error, that means something else in your queries is being interpreted as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up solving the problem by removing the "*" in front of [Form]...